# How to run Symfony Process function inside queue jobs on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-process

Now i'm doing some project use laravel framework. do i able to run Symfony Process function inside a queue jobs?

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

right now i want to run some commend using Symfony Process function for this

```
process = new Process("facebook-scraper --filename public/data/nintendo.csv --pages 5 nintendo");
```

if outside the queue. this code can run succesful. but when i want to make it run inside the queue jobs. it can't.

how do i able to run symfony Process function inside queue on jobs laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the paths. Replace the `--filename` option value with the absolute path (from /):

```php
$path = public_path('data/nintendo.csv');

$process = new Process("facebook-scraper --filename {$path} --pages 5 nintendo");

...
```

...

And try to use full path to executable (`facebook-scraper`).
You can use `which` to find it.

Example:

```sh
$ which facebook-scraper       
/usr/bin/facebook-scraper
```

Comment: thank you for the response. i've tried it but still same.. can't run the process function

Comment: @ferdinand I updated the answer. Try to use full path to executable.

Comment: yes!!!.. need to set full path to run the console command inside queue. thakn you!!!